Cartographic work in 4326 QGIS project
I am working on a project in QGIS whose CRS must be set to 4326. The problem is that when moving around the project map (without zoom in or out) the scale does not remain constant.
This is an understandable behavior since the CRS uses degrees, but the cartography does not respond well to it. When I determine that a layer symbol or label will be displayed from a certain scale, the question arises scale where? When I move around the map features disappear and appear depend on the latitude I am in, even if I don't zoom in or zoom out.
